# Bash Regular expression look ahead

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to trim a string to remove everything from begin until the last "[dit]" was found.
Therefore i use the following code:

```
 _annotation="[dit] pause"
 re="[a-z\~\*\-[:blank:]\[\]]*\[dit\](?![a-z\*\~\-[:blank:]]*\[dit\])"


 if [[ $_annotation =~ $re ]]; then
      _annotation=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      echo "expression found"
 fi
```

However there is a problem with the lookahead which i can't figure out. Even

```
re="[a-z\~\*\-[:blank:]\[\]]*\[dit\](?!\[dit\])"
```

is not finding the expression although there is no following "[dit]".

At the moment I can't help myself figuring out the problem.
Thank you for your help!

Cassidy

Comment: Bash uses Extended Regular Expressions, not Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions, so lookahead is not supported.

Comment: If you want "to remove everything" until the last `[dit]` why do you use a so complicated character class? With a dot (or a more simple character class that contains newlines too), you can use the simple fact that quantifiers are greedy by default to reach the last `[dit]` without to have to test what happens after.

Comment: If you want to strip a a prefix from the string, use `myval=${myval##*\[dit]}`. If you want to keep the last `[dit]`, it's easier to just put it back on to the result than to avoid removing it: `myval="${myval##*\[dit]}[dit]"`.